# EIGEN_MATRIXBASE_PLUGIN conflict with std::vector

Tags: eigen3

Failed to use EIGEN_MATRIXBASE_PLUGIN when add some user-defined function to Eigen::MatrixBase.

```
inline int minComponentId() const { int i; this->minCoeff(&i); return i; }//success
inline void vectorTest0() {std::vector<double> logic;}//success
inline void vectorTest1(std::vector<double> logic) {}//fail
```

I do this like the [Eigen documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizing_Plugins.html).The first function and the second are success but the third calls std::vector error.
[image: VS error information show like this]

I think std::vector may conflict with StdVector.h of Eigen Libary.
But how to use std::vector in EIGEN_MATRIXBASE_PLUGIN case?

Comment: Is this a build error or an IntelliSense error? `StdVector.h` is neither included by default, nor should it conflict with `std::vector`.

Comment: @chtz,thanks reply.it's a build error